# Выбор view в tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть проблемка с настройкой программированого tab bar. Я создал класс для кастомного tab bar, где в методе `viewWillAppear` огласил сам tab bar с нужными view:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let mondayTab = MondayTableViewController()
    mondayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Monday"
    mondayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let tuesdayTab = TuesdayTableViewController()
    tuesdayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Tuesday"
    tuesdayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let wednesdayTab = WednesdayTableViewController()
    wednesdayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Wednesday"
    wednesdayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let thursdayTab = TuesdayTableViewController()
    thursdayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Thursday"
    thursdayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let fridayTab = TuesdayTableViewController()
    fridayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Friday"
    fridayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let tabBarController = [mondayTab, tuesdayTab, wednesdayTab, thursdayTab, fridayTab]
    self.viewControllers = tabBarController

}
```

В функции `viewDidLoad`, того же класса я попытался различными способами изменить загрузочное view, например:

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

Но должного эффекта это не дало...

Comment: viewdidload происходит раньше, чем viewdidappear, таким образом вы пытаетесь выбрать первый таб до того, как он создан

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `viewDidLoad` вызывается раньше, чем `viewWillAppear`, таким образом, когда вы пытаетесь изменить индекс, у вашего таб бара еще не заданы все вью.

Чтобы это исправить либо вызывайте `selectedIndex` прямо в конце во `viewWillAppear`, либо меняйте всю логику чтобы выбор происходил после создания. Порядок следования методов делегата в этой ситуации viewDidLoad-viewWillAppear-viewDidAppear

Answer (score -1):

Твои кастомные таб бары надо поместить в функцию `awakeFromNib()`